# Speed up a program

Tags: python

Here is the implementation of `encode`

```
from transformers import BertTokenizer

def encode(self, document): 
    tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased")
    return tokenizer(document, 
                    max_length=50,
                    return_tensors='pt',
                    padding=True,
                    truncation=True)
```

When I ran

```
start = time.process_time()
train_articles = [self.encode(document) for document in dataset["train"]["article"][:100]]
print("Time:", time.process_time() - start)
```

the output was `Time: 34.859681388`. Be aware that each element in `dataset["train"]["article"]` is a list of approx. 47 sentences with in mean 15 words per sentence. The process is quite long to process only 100 documents. I am very new in programming. Is there a way to speed up the process? I have to run `self.encode` on 100000 documents, so I have to find a way to speed up the process.

Comment: If you are "very new in programming" and you are tasked with speeding up the code - and it looks like the problem domain is something relatively advanced (you didn't tell us anything useful, but from the names it seems to be something to do with neural networks, or perhaps natural language processing?), then you are *extremely in over your head*. I don't think it is possible to help you directly here. The first step you should take is to become less "new in programming". There are no shortcuts to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to improve performance is to use multi-thread pattern. In your case, if you are going to invoke this function many times in a process, it is better off adopting Python threading:

```
import threading
thd1 = threading.Thread("thread-1").spawn(encode)
for i in range(10):
   thd1.start
```

Now you are speeding up ten times.